# Match variable value to array's index to get month

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
example of getDepart date format

getDepart = 2022-04-29

desired result 29 APR, 2022

const getStringDepart = () => {

    const months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", 
    "NOV", "DEC"];
    const departArray = getDepart.split("-");
    const departDay = departArray[2];
    const departYear = departArray[0];
    const departMonth = ????????????
    const departString = `${departDay} ${departMonth}, ${departYear}`;
    return departString;

}
```

I'm trying to turn my YYYY-MM-DD string date format to a `DD mon, YYYY` string.
I was thinking about using an array with the months and matching the month number to it's index, but I can't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the `month - 1` on your array. It should return the month properly.

```
getDepart = '2022-04-29';

const getStringDepart = () => {
  const months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
  const departArray = getDepart.split("-");
  const departDay = departArray[2];
  const departYear = departArray[0];
  const departMonth = departArray[1];
  const departString = `${departDay} ${months[Number(departMonth) - 1]}, ${departYear}`;
  return departString;
}

function test() {
  console.log(getStringDepart())
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]